# Use table name in MySQL SELECT "AS"

Tags: mysql

I use the table name to build a nested array when I evaluate my MySQL SELECT JOIN result in PHP. However, when working with AS for calculated columns, I can't seem to set the table name as intended (to simplify, I am trying without a JOIN in this example, but the problem is the same):

```
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, "Test" AS `Table`.`field3` FROM `Test`;
```

This throws an error.

How can I indicate in the SQL, which table I want to associate field3 with?

(resulting in the table name in `$pdoStatement->getColumnMeta()` being "Table")

Answer (score 13):

To declare a string literal as an output column, leave the `Table` off and just use `Test`. It doesn't need to be associated with a table among your joins, since it will be accessed only by its column alias. When using a metadata function like `getColumnMeta()`, the table name will be an empty string because it *isn't* associated with a table.

```
SELECT
  `field1`, 
  `field2`, 
  'Test' AS `field3` 
FROM `Test`;
```

Note: I'm using single quotes above. MySQL is usually configured to honor double quotes for strings, but single quotes are more widely portable among RDBMS.

If you *must* have a table alias name with the literal value, you need to wrap it in a subquery with the same name as the table you want to use:

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM 
  /* subquery wraps all fields to put the literal inside a table */
  (SELECT field1, field2, 'Test' AS field3 FROM Test) AS Test
```

Now `field3` will come in the output as `Test.field3`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I think you misunderstand my intention. I wish to associate the declared column via AS to a specific table, so when I later evaluate the result set, the $pdoStatement->getColumnMeta() will think the table name is "Table1" instead of empty.

Comment: @preyz I get your intention, but you _cannot_ do that because the literal value is _not_ associated with any table. You can't trick it unless you join against a query that fakes it -- which I'll add above.

Comment: @preyz Added a hack above - this is really the only way.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT `field1`, `field2`, 'Test' AS `field3` FROM `Test`; // replace with simple quote '

Comment: Thanks, but I think you made the same assumption as Michael Berkowski below. Please see my comment to his answer.

Comment: I'am happy to help you preyz i copied pasted your script in the question, and i corrected, it's simple problem preyz